# How is a parent view controller notified that is's child view controller has removed itself?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

A child view controller is removed by the following code within the child view controller's implementation:

```
- (void)commandFinishVC
{
    [ self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [ self removeFromParentViewController ];
}
```

The child view controller and its view are successfully removed but how is the parent notified of this?  -viewDidDisappear is not called and -viewDidUnload has been deprecated.

From the examples I can find, it is always assumed that the parent view controller is the originator of the event nominating the child being removed but (to me) the child should be autonomous in it's logic for completion.

Should the remove methods be called by utilising the self.parentViewController property and using something like the following in the parent view controller?

```
- (void)commandFinishVC
{
    [ childVC.view removeFromSuperview];
    [ childVC removeFromParentViewController ];
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, your parent controller should generally control the addition and removal of the child controllers, so your second approach seems more applicable. See the [Implementing a Container View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) section of the *UIViewController Class Reference.*

I suspect you could get away with your former approach, where the child is removing itself, but Apple is consistent in their documentation and the WWDC 2011 session on [Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) says that the container controller bears the responsibility for managing children.

So, in answer to your question of how a child informs a parent that it's been removed, there is no established protocol for that. But this is unsurprising because it is presumed that the parent will be initiating this process. And to the extent that a child needs to initiate this process, the documentation suggests that the parent should have a public API for managing child controllers.

So while there is no protocol for a child informing the parent, there is, however, a published API by which parent controllers inform children that they have been moved/removed. Specifically, when the parent controller is removing a child, it should call [`willMoveToParentViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willMoveToParentViewController%3a). [This documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willMoveToParentViewController%3a) explicitly says that we must perform this notification:

> If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must call the `willMoveToParentViewController:` method of the child view controller before calling the `removeFromParentViewController` method...

Thus, as discussed in [Adding and Removing a Child](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW13) section of the *View Controller Programming Guide,* when removing a child, we should:

```
[childVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[childVC.view removeFromSuperview];
[childVC removeFromParentViewController];
```

Unsurprisingly, the documentation for [`didMoveToParentViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didMoveToParentViewController%3a) is equally unambiguous: When you add a child controller, you must call `didMoveToParentViewController` when the animation/transition (if any) is done. I don't know what would happen if we didn't call these two notification methods, but Apple says that we must and it therefore seems prudent to do so.

Comment: The reason behind this is the use of a VC (View Controller) container as a pure container, there are no views belonging to it.  The views within the child container have their associated events; so the action within the child VC (e.g. pressing a completion button) determines the release of the child VC.

Comment: Many thanks for replying, it really helps to clarify what I have been reading.

Comment: Rob, do you know if willMoveToParentViewController: is actually necessary if you're not overriding that method in your child view controller? Apple's docs make it sound like you're supposed to call this, but I can't figure out if it actually does anything, if you don't override it in your child. I haven't seen any problems if I don't call that method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it states in other Apple documentation that willMoveToParentViewController does nothing by default but I am unable to locate it again...  I also haven't encountered any issues from not calling it.

Comment: @rdelmar I don't know what happens if you don't call these methods, but the docs say that we "must." (The `animation` block of `transitionFromViewController` falls into the same category of something that is documented as "required", but in practice is often not needed.) So, in short, yes, you're right that the documentation says that we must call these methods, but whether that's true in practice or not is unclear. Personally, if the docs say we must do something (esp something as simple as a single method invocation), I generally do it in the spirit of good, defensive programming.

Comment: @Roddy I haven't seen that reference to the fact that the default `willMoveToParentViewController` doing nothing, but in the WWDC 2011 session, they go so far as to say that if you implement your own `willMoveToParentViewController`, that you would "of course" call the `super` implementation. You may very well be right that the default does nothing, but with language about the fact that we "must" call it, and that if we do have our own, we should call the `super` method, I would err towards calling it. It's a single call, so I see little downside in calling it.