# UITableViewController as dropdown?

Tags: ios, swift, childviewcontroller

I would like to create a `UITableViewController` as a dropdown on clicking a `UIButton`.

I have created one using `addChildViewController` but I cannot remove it by clicking the button a second time.

The code I used:

```
var flag = 0
func filter(sender: UIButton){
 let _viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserViewController") as! UserViewController
 if(flag == 1){
            _viewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
            _viewController.removeFromParentViewController()

        flag = 0
        return
    }

    addChildViewController(_viewController)
    _viewController.view.frame.origin.y = filterButton.frame.maxY
    _viewController.view.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width-250
    _viewController.view.frame.size.width = 250
    _viewController.view.frame.size.height = 500 
    self.view.addSubview(_viewController.view)
    flag = 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is simple because you are instantiating the view controller everytime you click the button.
    You should instantiate the `_viewController` in `viewDidLoad`. Also you must remove the view from superview on removing and make the self as parent on adding.

Refer this link for detail
    [How is a parent view controller notified that is's child view controller has removed itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166006/how-is-a-parent-view-controller-notified-that-iss-child-view-controller-has-rem).
    Your code should look like the following,

```
var _viewController:UITableViewController!
var flag = 0
func filter(sender: UIButton){

    if(flag == 1){
        _viewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        _viewController.view.removeFromSuperview() 
        _viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
        flag = 0
        return
    }

    addChildViewController(_viewController)
    _viewController.view.frame.origin.y = filterButton.frame.maxY
    _viewController.view.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width-250
    _viewController.view.frame.size.width = 250
    _viewController.view.frame.size.height = 500
    self.view.addSubview(_viewController.view)
    _viewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    flag = 1

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    _viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserViewController") as! UserViewController

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use drop downs. It is not something that belongs on iOS.

http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1950

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will look into that. Right now as a beginner i got my answer and learned new.